# Git Clone : Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm using bitbucket and I'm trying to clone a repo with : `sudo git clone git@bitbucket.org:KassaK/mbf.git`

I get this error :

```
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I search everywhere for a solution but with nothing good.

I folowed instructions from https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-ssh-for-git-728138079.html (to Step), but I always have this error.

I tried to remove and reinstall git but it's the same.

Any ideas for me ? Thanks !

Comment: You should not use `sudo` here in any case.

Comment: If you've got permissions issues with where you need the repository to be, such as the web server directory, then clone first to your home directory, then `sudo mv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For public key authentication system, It concern with host name, user name, key filename, etc., If you run with sudo, the user name will be **root**,  It is different with what you run ssh-keygen to create key pair.
So authentication failed.

Comment: It was something like that, I was trying to clone into a folder without godd permissions... Thanks !

Comment: Have a same problem. I run a command with sudo , the username is root. I logged to my remote server via ssh and authorized ssh key in bitbucket. Can't push project from bitbucket to remote server, same error as described.