# My own git server (on EC2) git clone via ssh (permission denied) why?

Tags: git, amazon-ec2, ssh, git-clone, git-server

I can connect from my pc to my EC2 git server using ssh ( i specified port 22 cause default port is onother):

```
$ ssh -p22 dev@xxxxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com
```

this works fine, but when I try to clone I have som problems(again i specified port 22 cause default port is onother):

```
sudo git clone ssh://dev@xxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com:22/home/dev/some/stuff.git
```

this is the output:

```
dev@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

why????

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to solve Permission denied (publickey) error when using Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2643502/how-to-solve-permission-denied-publickey-error-when-using-git)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git Clone : Permission denied (publickey). fatal: Could not read from remote repository](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38221255/git-clone-permission-denied-publickey-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-rep)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+sudo+Permission+denied+publickey

Comment: https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/error-permission-denied-publickey#should-the-sudo-command-be-used-with-git

Answer (score 1):

The reason is because you're using `sudo`.  OpenSSH uses the public keys of the current user to log in, and when you use `sudo`, they're the public keys of `root`, not your normal user.

If you want to clone as root, you either need to set up keys for root or set a `/root/.ssh/config` file that uses the normal user's keys via the `IdentityFile` option.  For example, if your normal user is `example` and you're using an Ed25519 key, the file might look like this:

```
Host xxxxxxxxxx.compute.amazonaws.com
    IdentityFile /home/example/.ssh/id_ed25519
```